# How to input test data using the DecisionTree module in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

On the Python DescisionTree module homepage ([DecisionTree-1.6.1](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/distDT/DecisionTree-1.6.1.html)), they give a piece of example code. Here it is:

```
dt = DecisionTree( training_datafile = "training.dat", debug1 = 1 )

dt.get_training_data()

dt.show_training_data()

root_node = dt.construct_decision_tree_classifier()

root_node.display_decision_tree(" ")

test_sample = ['exercising=>never', 'smoking=>heavy',
'fatIntake=>heavy', 'videoAddiction=>heavy']
classification = dt.classify(root_node, test_sample)

print "Classification: ", classification
```

My question is: How can I specify sample data (test_sample here) from variables? On the project homepage, it says: "You classify new data by first constructing a new data vector:" I have searched around but have been unable to find out what a data vector is or the answer to my question.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Um, the example says it all. It's a list of strings, with features and values separated by '=>'. To use the example, a feature is 'exercising', and the value is 'never'.

Comment: Ok. But how would I use variables?

Comment: test_sample is a variable. i think you might need to learn Python first. I've heard good things about http://byteofpython.info